# How can I download correct versions of mscordacwks and mscorwks?

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg, sos

I am trying to analyze an IIS memory dump usinf Windbg and SOS and ran into an issue with version of files mentioned above. My question is - is there a way I can download the different versions of these files? Assume that I have no access to the server and cannot copy them from the server. The versions I am specifically interested in is 
mscordacwks_x86_x86_2.0.50727.3603 and the corresponding mscorwks dll.

Comment: You don't need mscorwks.dll as it will already be part of your dump file, but you do need the correct version of mscordacwks.dll.

Comment: Just adding this note - When all else fails, follow instructions :). Setting up the symbol path in Windbg (srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols)
 will ensure that correct version of the mscodacwks is loaded.

Comment: I assumed you had already done that. However, in some rare cases this doesn't work and then you basically have to obtain the specific version manually.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following downloads the correct version of mscordacwks in WinDbg:

```
.symfix c:\symbols
.cordll -ve -u -l
```

Using WinDbg 6.2.9200.16384 and a dump with .NET 4.0.30319.296 / 4.0.30319.18034. Unfortunately I don't have a .NET 2 dump available with different .NET version than on my machine.

For those who have access to the PC where the dump comes from, you can try [Mscordcwks collector](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/download-mscordacwks-collector/).